# why is printf not called when expected?

Tags: c, printf

This is my Code [Note: I am using Eclipse for C/C++ on Windows Platform]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int num;
    printf("Enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    if(num%2==0)
        printf("Number is Even");
    else
        printf("Number is Odd");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here I have to enter an Integer first only then printf is called... I want to call printf first before I enter an Integer...What am I doing wrong here?

for example this is the output that I get

```
6
Enter a number:
Number is Even
```

and expected output is

```
Enter a number:
6
Number is Even
```

Comment: Is the problem that `scanf` is not returning, or that the final call to `printf` is not producing output?

Comment: Pleast post a [MCVE]. Specifically, which environment you are using. Also, are you using a normal shell or are you reading/writing input/output from a file or pipe?

Comment: If the program does not recognize `stdin/stdout` as an "interactive device", it will be fully buffered. In this case, output may be buffered until a call to `fflush(stdout)` (or one of a number of other function calls) is encountered.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY 
I tried removing \n still printf is not called

Comment: try `printf("Enter a number:\n");fflush(stdout);`

Comment: Note that your question should be "Why isn't the output from `printf()` appearing when expected?" since you've not produced any evidence that the calls are not made but only that you don't see the output you expect.

Comment: It Ok for me. I cant reproduce your problem on GCC.

Comment: The important part here is that you're using the **IDE** to **run the program** in a view in Eclipse, right? Then you need a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call fflush(stdout) after first printf to print the buffered output. But considering in future if you extend the program with more printfs then adding fflush after every printf will be an overhead. So you can add

> setbuf(stdout, NULL)

just before all the printfs. 
This will make sure no output is buffered and you will see the prints instantaneously.